# "Check that mate" : OED on usage of 'checkmate'

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context, collocation

In a recent post [How exactly is “to checkmate” used as a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229167/how-exactly-is-to-checkmate-used-as-a-verb?s=3|1.2317), the [answer given by @WS2](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/229170) listed some OED examples of metaphorical usage of 'to checkmate'. Among them:

> [1649 A. Ascham Bounds Publique Obed. 58 **At this distance he** [sc. Jas. I] **contrived how to extinguish or check that mate** [sc. the Kirk] **there.**]

(emphasis mine; cannot access OED; unlike other given examples enclosed in square brackets)

I find this example peculiar. In what sense does 'checkmate' occur as a verb here? And what is actually going on in this sentence? Is the word *mate* as occurring here cognate with *-mate* in 'checkmate'?

Can anyone shed some light on this? (I cannot even decipher the source.)

Comment: It's 350 years old. None of us are that old, even the ones in Scotland who play chess. I.e, it doesn't make any sense to us, either.

Comment: Without more context there's no way to know what the meaning is.  But note that both "check" and "mate" have multiple meanings.

Comment: The source is Antony Ascham’s 1649 work titled _The bounds & bonds of publique obedience. Or, A vindication of our lawfull submission to the present government, or to a government supposed unlawfull, but commanding lawfull things. Likewise how such an obedience is consistent with our Solemne League and Covenant. In all which a reply is made to the three answers of the two demurrers, and to the author of the grand case of conscience, who professe themselves impassionate Presbyterians_, available (but not OCR’ed, alas) [here](http://bit.ly/1vLF5hL).

Comment: It is also the only citation on the page that separates _check_ and _mate_ into two words. The square brackets surrounding it “indicates a quotation is relevant to the development of a sense but not directly illustrative of it” [OED how-to](http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-symbols-and-other-conventions/). My guess is this isn’t really the word _checkmate_ (‘your king is dead’), but the verb _check_ (‘stop’) and the noun _mate_ (‘friend’) being used to make a play on words.

Comment: Context: “For how came she [Mary Queen of Scots] to be Beheaded in England, but by _Mr._ Knox (and the Kirkes having done little better than) put her into the hands of those who could not keepe her long alive with security to themselves? King _James_ hath writ and argued largely concerning his dangers & sufferings under it, & it is yet remembred in what Dialect they of the Presbytery were wont to Preach and Pray against him to his face, and he not know how to remedy it, or by what right to top theirs. When he came into England he profest his deliverance from that subjection not [cont’d-->]

Comment: [-->cont’d] of small satisfaction to his minde and therefore **at this distance he contrived how to extinguish or check that mate there**, & after some progress in that worke he himselfe dyed peaceably in a milder Country.”

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Well, from that context it's still not clear what "mate" means (though perhaps someone with knowledge of the history will have some ideas).  But "extinguish or check" appears to be aimed at some political/religious/social process or movement, and sort of makes sense standing alone.  (It is vaguely possible, though, that "check that mate" was an idiom derived from chess.)

Comment: Many thanks, @JanusBahsJacquet! I could not see originally how 'the Kirk' might be a person, but it is clearer now. I also think it's a pun; that's perhaps why it is relevant to 'çheckmate' and was included in that entry: if it could be punned upon in 1649, the word must have been well established by then ... pure guessswork, of course.

Comment: @JohnLawler It must have made some sense to the editors of OED, otherwise how could it have been included? I'd assume there must have been a reasonable level of certainty (and of course they _must have foreseen_ that it will eventually be pondered upon at EL&U).

Comment: I don't doubt that it made sense to people who read it at the time -- some of them, at least -- and to the scholar who read the book and cited the sentence. But that's maybe a few dozen people, all of them dead. What sense it may have made to them is information that's as lost as if it fell into a black hole.

Answer (score 1):

This citation is listed under an [entry for *checkmate* in OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/31110?rskey=Mcv4d0&result=3) which reads:

> 2. *transf.* To arrest or defeat utterly, discomfit. In mod. use, often: to defeat or frustrate the ‘game’ or scheme of (any one) by a counter-movement.

This at least tells us which meaning of checkmate this is supposed to be relevant to (but not a direct example of, based on the OED's use of brackets).

I cannot explain the use of *mate* but it would appear that [*the Kirk*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kirk?s=t) in the note immediately after is *the Church* rather than a person.

If I were to speculate I would guess at a play of words between *checkmate* and [this meaning of *mate*, from OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/114905?rskey=H96TMc&result=2) or some variation thereof:

> †2. A suitable associate or equal adversary; an equal in status. *Obs.*

Comment: I am aware that 'the Kirk' usualy refers to the Church of Scotland. However, in the larger chunk of text retrieved by @Janus, in the phrase '(and the Kirkes having done little better than)', I read 'the Kirkes' as a plural. That would point to some kind of synecdoche, a 'Kirk' meaning a cleric (i.e., a person). If 'the Kirk' stands for 'the Church', what does 'the Kirkes' stand for?